# Javan Whenever Gem is sending me the output as local mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, whenever

**Javan's Whenever gem** for Ruby on Rails is fantastic, however, I'm having one issue with it, namely that it sends whatever output I've logged to **/var/mail/user**, which **I don't want to receive**.  Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Thanks,

Harris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever allows also to direct standard output and errors differently, for example to /dev/null if you don't want any mail or logging. For details, see: https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs

Answer (score 3):

Set

```
env :MAILTO, ""
```

http://groups.google.com/group/whenever-gem/browse_thread/thread/4eed7957127a72d4

Comment: This generates an error: `errors in crontab file, can't install`
Maybe `set :environment, "development"` ?  I'm on Rails 3 btw.

Comment: That's proper syntax according to their documentation: https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/instructions-and-examples Perhaps hit up their google group for help.